# Accidentally make all files uploaded as 9B octet/stream in firebase, is there anything i can do to recover it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, pdf, firebase-storage, octetstring

I was using firebase storage to upload user pdf file, and tested that it successfully uploaded. But unfortunately, the files are saved as 9B octet stream not pdf. I found the solution to upload files as pdf, but haven't found any solution to recover the uploaded octet stream files back as pdf. Is there any possible way to convert the files back to pdf?

[The firebase dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmagG.png)

Comment: You can make changes using the Google Cloud console for the same bucket that you're using through Firebase.  Google Cloud Storage and Firebase Storage are the same underlying product.

Comment: If the Firebase console says the file size is 9 bytes, there is nothing more than those 9 bytes that it has stored. Since you never uploaded the full PDF, there is no way to retrieve that PDF data from Firebase/Cloud Storage.